# Can't find MSVCP80.dll (side by side problem?)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, msvcrt

when I try to start the release-version of my project from visual studio 2005 (SP1) I get the following error message:

"This application has failed to start because MSVCP80.dll was not found. Re-installing the application may fix this problem"

When I look at the manifest for the release version it specifies the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity type="win32" name="Microsoft.VC80.CRT" version="8.0.50727.762" processorArchitecture="x86" publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b"></assemblyIdentity>
    </dependentAssembly>
  </dependency>
</assembly>
```

When I look in the Windows/WinSxS folder I have the following versions of the CRT:

```
x86_Microsoft.VC80.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.1433_x-ww_5cf844d2
x86_Microsoft.VC80.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.163_x-ww_681e29fb
x86_Microsoft.VC80.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.3053_x-ww_b80fa8ca
x86_Microsoft.VC80.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.42_x-ww_0de06acd
x86_Microsoft.VC80.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.762_x-ww_6b128700
```

All these folders contains the required dll. On my stationary computer, with the exact same version of visual studio everything works fine.

Here's the kicker, I mananaged to start the program exactly once in both release and debug before the problem surfaced. The output from the debug-build showed that the *DebugCRT*.762*-dlls from the WinSxS were loaded the first time but now when I try to start the program it fails to find these dlls.

The only external dependency is ws2_32.lib.

I've just reinstalled everything on the laptop (Windows XP, visual studio, service packs etc) but to no avail.

If I remove the reference to ws2_32.lib the program starts.

Please help me, I'm about to throw my brand new laptop out the window :(

Kind Regards

Andreas Brinck

Answer (score 3):

can be a registry problem. Do what is suggested and reinstall MS CRT

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=200b2fd9-ae1a-4a14-984d-389c36f85647

this is the version used in VS 2005 SP1.

Also check your VS installation, you should have these dlls also in

%program files%\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\redist\x86\Microsoft.VC80.CRT

if not you can do repair on your VS 2005 installation.

hope this helps.

cheers,

Perica